# I want rows to column with type wise in JavaScript. is it possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop

I have a Array in multiple type e.g **Time-In or Time-Out** , **Break-in ,Break-out** etc.
here is list

```
const data = 
  [ { 
    , entryDateTime             : '02:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : 'dgdfgdfg'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '03:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { 
    , entryDateTime             : '04:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { timeSheetDetailActivityId : 0
    , timeSheetDailyActivityId  : 0
    , entryDateTime             : '05:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Break Out'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , { 
    , entryDateTime             : '06:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time In'
    , comments                  : '2323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  , {
    , entryDateTime             : '07:28'
    , activityTypeId            : 'Time Out'
    , comments                  : '232323'
    , isLeave                   : ''
    } 
  ]
```

i want above list to like this

```
[ {
  , Time In                  : '02:28'
  , Time Out                 : '03:28'
  , Break In                 : '02:28'
  , Break Out                : '03:28'
  } 
, { 
  , Time In                  : '06:28'
  , Time Out                 : '08:28'
  , Break In                 : '02:28'
  , Break Out                : '03:28'
  } 
]
```

how is possible?

i ll be thanks full to all am stuck from 2 days
Please help me or give some time on it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, piece of cake.

Build an object that keeps track of your data per activity ID, then read it.

```
const groupedData = {};
data.forEach(({ timeSheetDailyActivityId, activityTypeId, entryDateTime }) => {
  // Retrieve group object from `groupedData`,
  // initialize one (assigning it back) if it doesn't yet exist.
  const group =
    groupedData[timeSheetDailyActivityId] ||
    (groupedData[timeSheetDailyActivityId] = { timeSheetDailyActivityId });
  // Add the activity->datetime mapping to the group.
  group[activityTypeId] = entryDateTime;
});
// Since `groupedData` is an object and we want an array, use `Object.values`.
console.log(Object.values(groupedData));
```

This prints out e.g. (after changing the example input data a bit so there are multiple `dailyId`s):

```
[
  {
    timeSheetDailyActivityId: 0,
    'Time In': '02:28',
    'Time Out': '03:28',
    'Break In': '04:28',
    'Break Out': '05:28'
  },
  {
    timeSheetDailyActivityId: 1,
    'Time In': '06:28',
    'Time Out': '07:28'
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks it help me much
yes it multiple show dailyId if i remove then what happed?
i remove dailyId please check now.

Comment: What _should_ happen if there's no valid key to group the entries with?

Comment: i upload pic please check from here :https://paste.pics/bb699031f799767edc9859814517df22

Comment: i remove timeSheetDailyActivityId or send you screenshoot

Comment: Well, without any `timeSheetDailyActivityId`, all of the items would be grouped under an `"undefined"` key.

Comment: but i need like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UesYV.png

Comment: What would be the logic for "like that"? How should the program know when to start a new "row"?